# Integers of values 0 to show 2 digits or decimal places - flutter

Tags: flutter, int, double

Hi there I am having trouble displaying a variable with a value of zero ith more the one place except for in the terminal.

i have 2 simple variables that I initialize at the start of my app

int players = 00
double pot = 00.00

id like my variable to be displayed on the screen like that when the app fist starts but it always reverts player to 0 and pot to 0.0

I've had no luck with doing that with the text widget it will only show 1 zero

```
Text(
              'Players : $players',
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 25.0),
            ),
            Text(
              'Current Pot :  $pot',
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 25.0),
            ),
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

It isn't exactly clear what behavior is expected when the value of `players` and the value of `pot` changes. You are probably seeking something along the lines of `players.toString().padLeft(2, '0')` and `pot.toStringAsFixed(2).padLeft(5, '0')`. Behavior shown when these values change in [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/15d068d74ab25bcd25298f95301056e2).